# RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, telethon

Помогите исправить ошибку, чет вообще не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError('__enter__')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\allBot\main.py", line 23, in main
    with bot:
AttributeError: __enter__
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:1897: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
  handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
from aiogram import  Bot, Dispatcher,executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio
api_id =   # Your API_ID
api_hash = ""  # Your APP_ID
bot_token = ""  # (via botfather, you can alternatively sign in as a user)
goupid = -4075187420
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
#users = []


@dp.message_handler(commands=['all'])
async def main(message: types.Message):
    async def get_users(client, group_id):
        async for user in client.iter_participants(group_id):
            if not user.deleted:
                print(user.username)
                # users.append(user.username)

    bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
    with bot:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_users(bot, goupid))
    #for i in users:

        #if i == None:
        #    continue
        #else:
        #    await message.answer("@"+i)



executor.start_polling(dp)
```